# Python3.6.0でGmailのUTF-8メールのデコードに失敗

Tags: python, macos, python3, gmail

OS-X SieraとPython3.6.0でGmailのメールを取り出すスクリプトを書いています。

文字コードがiso-2022-jpのメールはbodyをデコードできるのですが、UTF-8の場合、デコードに失敗します。

出力結果を見る限り、文字コードの取得は成功しているようなのですが、なぜUTF-8で失敗するのか、分かりません。

どなたか解決方法をご教示頂けないでしょうか。よろしくお願い申し上げます。

---

### 実行例

1 : テストメール1
2017/03/23 15:25:28
iso-2022-jp

1行目。
2行目。

2 : テストメール2
2017/03/23 17:44:33
utf-8
CjHooYznm67jgIIKMuihjOebruOAggo=

---

### ソース

```
import imaplib
import email
import os
import sys
import dateutil.parser

def main():
    gmail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")

    try:
        gmail.login("xxxxxxx@gmail.com","*******")
        gmail.select('Notes')
        typ, [data] = gmail.search(None, "(ALL)")

        #取得したメール一覧の処理
        cnt = 0

        for num in data.split():
            cnt += 1
            ### 各メールへの処理 ###
            result, d = gmail.fetch(num, "(RFC822)")
            raw_email = d[0][1]
            msg = email.message_from_bytes(raw_email)

            #文字コード取得用
            msg = email.message_from_string(raw_email.decode('iso-2022-jp'))
            msg_encoding = email.header.decode_header(msg.get('Subject'))[0][1] or 'iso-2022-jp'

            #パースして解析準備
            msg = email.message_from_string(raw_email.decode(msg_encoding))

            date = dateutil.parser.parse(msg.get('Date')).strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")

            subject = email.header.decode_header(msg.get('Subject'))
            title = ""
            for sub in subject:
                if isinstance(sub[0], bytes):
                    title += sub[0].decode(msg_encoding)
                else:
                    title += sub[0]

            body = ""
            if msg.is_multipart():
                for payload in msg.get_payload():
                    if payload.get_content_type() == "text/plain":
                        body = payload.get_payload()
            else:
                if msg.get_content_type() == "text/plain":
                    body = msg.get_payload()

            print(str(cnt) + " : " + title)
            print(date)
            print(msg_encoding)
            print(body)
            print('')
    finally:
        gmail.close()
        gmail.logout()
        return(cnt)

##メイン
main()
```

---

ご教示いただいた内容を元に、bodyの取得処理にBase64のデコード処理を追加したところ、UTF-8のメールを正常に取得できるようになりました。
以下に修正後のソースを載せます（try句を外して整理しています）。

### 修正後のソース

```
import imaplib
import email
import dateutil.parser
import base64

def main():
    gmail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
    gmail.login("xxxxxxx@gmail.com","xxxxxxxxxxx")
    gmail.select('Notes')
    typ, [data] = gmail.search(None, "(ALL)")

    #取得したメール一覧の処理
    for num in data.split():
        print(num)

        ### 各メールへの処理 ###
        result, d = gmail.fetch(num, "(RFC822)")
        raw_email = d[0][1]

        #文字コード取得用
        msg = email.message_from_string(raw_email.decode('iso-2022-jp'))
        msg_encoding = email.header.decode_header(msg.get('Subject'))[0][1] or 'iso-2022-jp'

        print(msg_encoding)

        date = dateutil.parser.parse(msg.get('Date')).strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")

        print(date)

        subject = email.header.decode_header(msg.get('Subject'))
        title = ""
        for sub in subject:
            if isinstance(sub[0], bytes):
                title += sub[0].decode(msg_encoding)
            else:
                title += sub[0]

        print(title)

        body = ""
        if msg.is_multipart():
            for payload in msg.get_payload():
                if payload.get_content_type() == "text/plain":
                    body = payload.get_payload()
                    if msg_encoding == 'utf-8':
                        body = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(body.encode('ASCII')).decode("utf-8")
        else:
            if msg.get_content_type() == "text/plain":
                body = msg.get_payload()
                if msg_encoding == 'utf-8':
                    body = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(body.encode('ASCII')).decode("utf-8")
        print(body)
        print('')
    gmail.close()
    gmail.logout()
    return(0)

main()
```

---

以下のコードでContent-Type内のcharsetを取得できました。

### 追加コード

```
s = email.header.decode_header(msg.get('Content-Type'))[0]
ss = repr(s[0]).split(';')
if len(ss) > 1:
    c = ss[1].split('charset="')
    if len(c) > 1:
        code = c[1].split('"')
        if len(code) > 1:
            msg_encoding = code[0]
```

Comment: 失敗した際のログもあると答えやすいと思います

Answer (score 2, accepted):

下記にて本文文字列をタイトルで指定されたエンコード方式にてデコードしているようですが

```
msg = email.message_from_string(raw_email.decode(msg_encoding))
```

テストメール2の
CjHooYznm67jgIIKMuihjOebruOAggo=
はUTF-8文字列をBase64エンコードされているように見えますので、
まずBase64デコードが必要です。

※蛇足：
昔のメールサーバーは7bitコードしか処理できないという制約があり、
7bitコードで扱えるように出てきたのがBase64であり、QuotedPrintableであり、ISO-2022-JPです。
ISO-2022-JPは一見8bit使用の2byteコードに見えますが各オクテットは7bit範囲内であり、ASCII領域と日本語文字領域の被り部分はエスケープシーケンスを使うことにより切り替えを行います。
base64は各byteを6bitづつに区切り、ASCII文字列として再生成する仕組みです。
QPはASCII領域はそのまま、それ以外はASCII文字を使用し文字コードで表現する方法です。

Comment: H.Mayuさん、ご教示ありがとうございました。

Comment: 今回ご提示のコードはテストコードに見えますが、実際のメールのエンコーディングを調査するにはメールヘッダを見る必要があります。Content-Typeに文字エンコーディング(UTF-8,ISO-2022-jp等).Content-Transfer-Encodingにエンコード情報(base64,quoted-printable等)が記載されています。

Comment: コメントありがとうございました。  
汚いですが、以下のコードでContent-Typeから文字コードセットを取得できました。  
    s = email.header.decode_header(msg.get('Content-Type'))[0]  
    ss = repr(s[0]).split(';')  
    if len(ss) > 1:  
        c = ss[1].split('charset="')  
        if len(c) > 1:  
            code = c[1].split('"')  
            if len(code) > 1:  
                msg_encoding = code[0]